# CORS Issue loading static resources in lightning

Tags: lightning, sandbox, winter21

In Winter '21 we have started getting a CORS error when loading resources from static resources. We believe it relates to [this](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_lc_secure_static_resources_update.htm).

If this is the intended behaviour, what is the recommended way of sharing resources between lightning components?

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://post-test-org-ent-ed--org3--staticresourcet.visualforce.com/resource/1601918961000/staticresourcet__CommonBundle/vendor/orgApps/LightningUtility.js?staticResourceOrigin=https%3A%2F%2Fpost-test-org-ent-ed--org3.lightning.force.com. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match 'https://post-test-org-ent-ed--org3.lightning.force.com').
```

This is the code i'm using to test this issue out.

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!join(',',
                       $Resource.staticresourcet__CommonBundle + '/vendor/orgApps/LightningUtility.js')}"
              afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.init}" />
```

We have only seen this in lightning aura components.

Comment: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001JipTQAS